# Magento: Getting Product Url's for Products within a Grouped Product

Tags: php, magento, url, product

For a grouped product, I would like to display a link to the simple products it is composed of. For example, if I have a grouped product called Dining Set composed of plates, knives, forks, etc. I'd like each of the subproducts to have a link to that subproduct (click plates goes to the Simple Product for plates)

```
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
        </td>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">View</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock.') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is a code snippet from the grouped.phtml file in

```
app/design/frontend/blank/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

In particular the line that has `$_item->getProductUrl()`,
this does not work, and I don't know the code needed to get the url for this associated product item. If anyone could help here it would be much appreciated.

Also, where on earth can I find the method's available (and how they're used) for Products or Categories or `$_item` and the like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy to find all methods and functions. Always trace back to the Core `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` or any of the other files in that Folder.

Your code is perfect. Just use

```
$_item->getUrlPath() ;
```

instead of `productURL`.

Comment: Most times you can make a guess...
I create new attributes like finish, dimensions, lead_time etc. Within the loop, call for getData('lead_time') and it just works! Brilliant ORM!

Answer (score 5):

Just a few notes on getting the available methods / data:

First, to get all methods actually coded into the classes, you can get all the available methods with:

```
$array = get_class_methods($_item); //yields an array of the methods in the class
var_dump($array); // to see the methods
```

To get all data-related methods, first find out the data members in the class. This works with most objects in Magento:

```
$data = $_item->getData(); // $key => $value array
```

Then you can get any piece of data you want two ways:

```
// assuming I want 'my_data'
$data = $_item->getMyData();
$data = $_item->getData('my_data');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getProductUrl()) ?>
```

or here is the whole A HREF:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getProductUrl()) ?>">
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>
</a>
```